# Create webhook with only ruby?

Tags: ruby, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm creating a telegram bot in ruby , right now I'm using long polling , but I wanna change to webhooks, but I'm only found information about creating webhooks in rails , so I don't know if is possible to set a webhook in a ruby only project.

Anyone did this? or have a tutorial? Maybe a lighter application in sinatra or rails api mode?

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a simple socket server: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html

However, creating a Rails app with one route for the web hook will not take you a lot of time. This will also give you a lot of flexibility to do more with your inbound data and app in the future e.g. admin dashboard, security, background processing, etc.